# Preserve order from dictionary keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to extract the dictionary keys, preserving their order (CTY, LC, DIV).  When I perform a list comprehension, it is automatically ordering them.

[image: [dictionary with keys]

```
columns = [key for key in dict_columns.keys()]
```

[image: [generated list]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

consider using an OrderedDict to preserve the order of keys in your dict

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict